# Partitioning through block moves to the end

Tags: algorithms, sorting, strings, binary

Suppose we have a binary string $s$. We wish to partition this string in a series of $0$s followed by $1$s (alternatively: we wish to sort), using only one operation: moving three consecutive elements to the end.

E.g. if our string is $ABCDEFGH$ we can do our operation at index $1$ to get $DEFGHABC$. If we did it at index $4$ we'd get $ABCGHDEF$.

I'm interested in optimal solutions - that is with the least amount of moves. I have a working algorithm using IDA* with heuristic "# of groups of ones with length $\leq 3$ before the final zero", with the logic that each such a group requires at least one move to fix. An example optimal solution (where `^` indicates where a block was chosen to move to the end):

```
1101101011101011010010010011                               
                       ^                                   
1101101011101011010010011100                               
                     ^                                     
1101101011101011010011100001                               
              ^                                            
1101101011101010011100001110                               
           ^                                               
1101101011110011100001110010                               
                        ^                                  
1101101011110011100001110001                               
     ^                                                     
1101111110011100001110001010                               
  ^                                                        
1111110011100001110001010011                               
                     ^                                     
1111110011100001110000011101                               
                       ^                                   
1111110011100001110000001111                               
               ^                                           
1111110011100000000001111111                               
        ^                                                  
1111110000000000001111111111                               
   ^                                                       
1110000000000001111111111111                               
^                                                          
0000000000001111111111111111
```

However, this algorithm is exponential and not feasible for larger strings. After studying quite some optimal solutions, especially tough ones like above, I can't immediately think of an optimal algorithm. Moves can be quite non-trivial.

Is there a feasible optimal algorithm? Or is this problem hard?

Comment: I'm not yet sure that "# of groups of ones with length ≤ 3 before the final zero" is an admissible heuristic -- aren't there possibly situations where $k$ copies of `101`, which contains 2 such groups, could be solved with fewer than $2k$ moves?

Comment: Within any consecutive subsequence of moves that do not overlap (that is, every pair of starting positions is separated by at least 3), the order that two moves *of the same triple pattern* take place has no effect.  That means that there is never any point investigating a solution in which we move a triple with pattern $x$ at position $p$, if (a) our most recent previous move of an $x$-patterned triple had starting position $q \ge p+3$ and (b) all moves performed between then and now were nonoverlapping.  This rule won't make anything polynomial-time, but might reduce the explosion a bit.